# AppEngine - JDO query !contains

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jdo, google-cloud-datastore, datanucleus

I'm using Google App Engine with JDO.
Trying to get entities where a collection of strings doesn't contain a specific string:

```
!viewers.contains('aaa')
"App Engine datastore does not support operator NOT"
```

Any workarounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GAE queries are always performed on indexes. However, the `does not include string` query needs a table scan. Such query is not possible on GAE.